# Unable to rotate image when using `imageWithRenderingMode` in swift

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uiimageview

This might not be a bug with Swift, but I find it really odd.

I'm trying to apply an SVG file to an `UIImageView`. To turn the SVG file into a `UIImage` I'm using this method:

```
class func imageFromPath(name: String) -> SVGKImage? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType:"svg", inDirectory:"SVG") {
       return SVGKImage(contentsOfFile: path)

    }
   return nil
}
```

The issue with the image is that it was flipped wrong and looked like this when I added it to an `UIImageView` using this method:

```
let image = ImageHelper.imageFromPath("icon-arrow-left")?.UIImage
```

[image]

Then I tired the following method to flip it so that it points up:

```
let flippedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .Right)
```

[image]

Then I wanted to be able to apply a tint to the `UIImageView` that it's located in, so I did this:

```
let flippedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .Right).imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
```

Which resulted in this:

[image]

I have tried `.Up`, `.Left`, `.Right` etc, but it only seems to point either to the left or to the right. What's up with that?

Comment: then it points to the left...

Comment: .imageOrientation is only a get property cannot edit it

Comment: so why is it in the constructor then? I clearly can edit it